Problemas al obtener created_at en laravel
Cuando intento obtener los datos de la DB (postgreSQL) el campo created_at viene en un formato distinto al que esta guardado en la DB,
en la DB el formato 2024-08-20 22:19:07 pero al obtener los datos con eloquent y obtener mi recurso en JSON me llega de la siguiente forma 2024-08-20T23:04:55.000000Z, en mi configuración regional en el archivo config/app.php tengo el time zone configurado de la siguiente forma.
'timezone' => 'America/Bogota'

trate de casts al campo created_at en el modelo de la siguiente forma.
protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s'
    ];

y el resultado es el siguiente.
"created_at": "2024-08-20 23:04:55",

al parecer una hora adelantado y los minutos tampoco coinciden como podría solucionar este inconveniente.
MODELO
<?php

namespace App\Models\BackOffice\Restaurant;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Command extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $table = "command";
    protected $primaryKey = "command_uuid";
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s'
    ];        

    protected $hidden = ['company'];

    public function command_detail(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CommandDetail::class, 'command')->orderBy('id' , 'asc');
    }
}

CONTROLADOR
public function index()
    {
        try {
            $command = Command::with(['command_detail'])
                ->join('table', 'table.id', '=', 'table')
                ->where('command.company', Auth::user()->company)
                ->where('finalized', '=', false)
                ->get();
            $data = [
                'code' => Response::HTTP_OK,
                'command' => $command
            ];
        } catch (QueryException $e) {

            $data = [
                'code' => Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                'code_error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'message' => 'Error al realizar la consulta'
            ];
        }

        return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
    }

